# hint for solving in $t$, the following equation $t^2e^{a^2\,/t} + a^2e^t-12at=0$

Tags: transcendental-equations

Please give me a hint in order to solve in t, the following equation:

$$t^2e^{a^2\!/t} + a^2e^t-12at=0$$

where $a=\ln(4)$.

Comment: I can suggest two improvements to your question. First, please typeset your math using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), otherwise no-one will want to read your question. Second, explain what you've tried, where you got stuck, and in general [avoid "no-clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: are you looking for "exact" or approximate solution ?

Comment: First of all I need a hint... Can't exponentiate it, can't use W lambert. In fact I can, but, this doesn't do any good, because I obtain some ugly expression. If I divide by e^((a^2)/t)) or by e^t, is no use either. Of course I can change the terms and so on. Of, and I can't raise to the power of t, or (a^2)/t), either, because again I obtain something ugly.  As I said, I don't need to be solve by you, but only a hint. And just for the record, t is a substitution for log(x), from another equation. I look for an exact solution, because from there I must put it in another equation.

Comment: [Newtons method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: plug in $t:=a\cdot x$ for a new unknown $x$. This simplifies the equation a bit and (provided I didn't make a computation error) if you plug in $a=\ln(4)$ and then try some small integers for $x$ you will find a solution.

**Edit:** You already found $x^2*e^{a/x}+e^{ax}-12*x=0$. Now plug in $a=\ln(4)$ gives $$x^24^{1/x} + 4^x = 12x$$
Pluggin in $x=2$ gives a solution.

Note that this uses being lucky with your specific equation. If you replace the $12$ by a $13$ I don't think there is any way to solve this algebraically.

Comment: I will let you know about what I did, probably tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: This don't work either... (a^2)*(x^2)*(e^((a^2)/(a*x)))+(a^2)*e^(ax)-12(a^2)*x=0 Which mean ((x^2)*(e^((a/x)))+e^(ax)-12*x=0, and **** this close to my initial eqation to solve, which I didn't mention here yet... in fact is the same pattern.

Comment: 0.5 is also a solution. But I don't see how you solved it... I design myself the equation so I know that 0.5 and 2 are solution. I could easily solve it by plotting. But, I wanted to know how to solve it, and I didn't find a way of solving, except plot and guesses... The last doesn't apply because I know the answers... So, if there are no ways of solving other the plotting or / and "try and guess", bisection method and other "not-exacted" ways ... please tell me so. Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution $x=2$ by guessing. I don't think there is a way to solve this kind of equation algebraically.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I only played, and it was only for (my) fun. I have designed a lot of similar kind of equation, but only in some special cases I could find a solution without plots and try and guesses.